# Facebook Comment plugin for website not updating in realtime

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I thought the [Facebook Comment Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) was supposed to show all comments, but it doesn't update comments in real time and says "No recent comments". I know there were comments posted on a web page on my site, just a few minutes ago.

Is there any another way to see all Facebook comments posted on my website, instead  to go to other web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the only area to see all comments from a site.

To see a particular URL you can use this API call

`You can check this using https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=YOUR_URL`